# google domain shared contacts appscript, using oauth2 lib and SharedContactsApp lib error on listAllContacts

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I am using **oauth2.0** library
(Google open source OAuth2 library `MswhXl8fVhTFUH_Q3UOJbXvxhMjh3Sh48`)

I am also using [**SharedContactsApp** library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/shared-contacts)
(open source library  `MLbRKmnCytdiSBOmoaGe1DOVJ5jnXUK_T`)

I am able to add a shared contact also add phone numbers. 
I am also able to use

```
SharedContactsApp.getContacts();
```

but when I do, I notice that I am only getting 25 contacts that I added no contacts that are also in domain and showing in the Directory option in contacts.
I have created more than 25 but when I use `getContacts()`, I only get 25.
So I decided to use `getContactsForPaging`.

But I am getting an error when using `SharedContactsApp.getContactsForPaging(Token);`.

This is how I have it set up:

```
function listAllContacts() {
   var sharedContactsService = getSharedContactsService();
   var Token = sharedContactsService.getAccessToken();
   SharedContactsApp.setOAuth2AccessToken(Token);

  do {
    var result = SharedContactsApp.getContactsForPaging(Token);
    contacts = result.getContacts();
    Token = result.getToken();
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
      Logger.log(contacts[i].getFullName());
    }
  } while (Token != null);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

This is my error:

```
Exception: Request failed for https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/dev.whitestratus.com/full/ returned code 401. 
  Truncated server response: <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
  <title>Error 401 (Client Error)!!1</title> <style type="text/css"> ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) 
  (line 239, file "Code", project "SharedContactsApp")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP 401 errors will be authentication related. My guess is that you don't have valid OAuth access. To confirm,

```
function tinyTest() {
  Logger.log('hasAccess() is: %s', getSharedContactsService().hasAccess()); 
}
```

should result in `'hasAccess() is: true'`. If it's `false`, you need to do two things:

1. Follow the [How To use OAuth 2 with SharedContactsApp](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/shared-contacts/oauth-2-with-sharedcontactsapp%20%22How%20to%20use%20OAuth2%20with%20SharedContactsApp). This will walk you through getting an access token which is a manual exercise, really complex and error prone. Carefully follow and check each step again and don't assume anything or try to take short cuts.
2. Use the `test()` function on that page (step 6 there) to confirm your setup before going any further or using your own code. If `test()` doesn't work your code won't either.

If your `test()` fails, I suggest that you report here with details from steps 2,3,4,5 (but hide your "client secret").

Edited to add:

If your test passes, then all seems OK with your OAuth. Run the code below to page through all your contacts and log on the way. Perhaps you have some contact/s with bad data. Look at the log and you'll see the id of the first contact that fails. Delete that contact and try again until you have no errors.

```
function listAllContacts() {
  SharedContactsApp.setOAuth2AccessToken(getSharedContactsService().getAccessToken());
  var contacts = null;
  var token = null;
  do {
    var result = SharedContactsApp.getContactsForPaging(token);
    contacts = result.getContacts();
    token = result.getToken();
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
      Logger.log(contacts[i].getId());
      Logger.log(contacts[i].getGivenName());
      Logger.log(contacts[i].getFamilyName());
      Logger.log(contacts[i].getFullName());
    }
  } while (token != null);
}
```

Comment: When I use the tinyTest(). if logs false to me. but for the test function I get a contact. also when I use getContacts(). Both work for me but not getContactsForPaging().

Comment: For some reason the first time i tried the **tinyTest()** I got false, but I am getting true now all the time I run it. I followed the instructions on the oauth for shared contacts. But still get errors when I do **getContactsForPaging()** .  I am able to add, delete and edit Users with the library as well, but cant get them by paging. @peter

Comment: What is the error message now (still the same 401?). Perhaps you have some contact/s with bad data?. Insert "Logger.log(contacts[i].getId());" before the logger you have and run it. Look at the log and you'll see the id that fails. Delete it and try again until you have a clean data set.

Comment: yes. is 401. i tried again the ** tinyTest()** and gave me false so I did the authentication again. Then I ran it again and game me true. Then ran **test()** and **SharedContactsApp.getContacts();** and both worked but not **SharedContactsApp.getContactsForPaging(Token);** Should I share my Project ID Here?  @Peter

Comment: I edited my answer, adding what to do now that we know your OAuth test passes (fyi, re the tinyTest() failing the first time: the OAuth token expires every 60 mins but the .getAccessToken() automatically refreshes it.

Comment: Thanks It works but it doesn't return domain contacts that are shown in Directory shared contacts. should it return them or the api keeps them out for safety? also I notice your library doesnt have edit name or last name, or some others, should deleting and adding be the approach?

Comment: That's great news. What fixed it? As the author of the question, you'll see an outline of a checkmark on the left side of each answer. It'll be right below the up and down vote arrows. Click the checkmark next to the post that best answers your question to accept that answer as the best one. Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows. Feel free to research and/or create new questions for your other queries.

Comment: The problem was arround 2 errors. One error was on the token giving me the problem with authentication. The second error was that I had 2 .gs files one for the oauth and another for listing. And as I was testing I left a copy of the function listAllContacts() in the auth.gs file. This copy is the example on the shared contacts library page, which doesnt include the getSharedContactsService part. My other file had the version with the service included but both function were called the same. and when I was running it for some reason appscript was always picking the function from the oauth file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Token` for two different things. There are two tokens the OAuth2 token and the paging token. This should fix it.

```
function listAllContacts() {
var sharedContactsService = getSharedContactsService();
var oaToken = sharedContactsService.getAccessToken();
SharedContactsApp.setOAuth2AccessToken(oaToken);
var Token = null;
var contacts = null;


do { 
var result = SharedContactsApp.getContactsForPaging(Token);
contacts = result.getContacts();
Token = result.getToken();
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
Logger.log(contacts[i].getFullName());
}
} while (Token != null);
}
```

Comment: Exception: Request failed for https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/dev.whitestratus.com/full/ returned code 401. Truncated server response: <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <title>Error 401 (Client Error)!!1</title> <style type="text/css"> ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 239, file "Code", project "SharedContactsApp")

Comment: Error 401 is Unauthenticated.  Is this running under a domain account that has the authorization to read and modify user accounts?

Comment: Hello @Spencer-Easton. Yes. The user is an admin in the domain. I also added Then client ID and scopes under Manage API client access in the Google admin console, because I though that would be a reason. But still get 401. The weird part is that it only happens when I use function **SharedContactsApp.getContactsForPaging(Token);**. Because I am able to  use **SharedContactsApp.getContacts();** And I am able to use add. and edit some of the fields. example of me adding in a loop. **SharedContactsApp.createContact("gela"+i, "contactos"+i, "user@gmail.com");**